# how to show image on email body - using sksmtplibrary

Tags: ios, email, smtp

I have a html content as my email body. I need show an image on my html body. I have tried attaching the image to email and used the filename in html image tag. But the image is not showing. I have also tried using dataUri, which doesnt work in certain email clients.

This is my code.

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSDataalloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURLURLWithString: @"http://wf.vanillicon.com/f6f63a5a0d149275772ff1cf22595988_100.png"]];
NSString *strFileName = [NSStringWithFormat:@"MyPicture.png"];

NSString *strFormat = [NSStringWithFormat:@"image/png;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"%@\"",strFileName];
NSString *strFormat2 = [NSStringWithFormat:@"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"%@\"",strFileName];
NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strFormat,kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                         strFormat2,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[imageData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
testMsg.parts = [NSArrayarrayWithObject:vcfPart];

NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           @"<img src=\"MyPicture.png\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\" /><h1>Tui</h1>",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                          @"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
testMsg.parts = [NSArrayarrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

find out demo codes of email sending via SMPT from below links

https://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/trunk/SMTPSender/Classes/SMTPSenderAppDelegate.m

or

https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp

or

http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/04/15/Send-email-with-attachments-on-iPhone.aspx

you may be succeed

Comment: I want to send email usin SMTP. Thats why i am using SKSMTPLibrary

Comment: find out demos from above urls and make needful changes

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you send an HTML email, and you have an image in a tag in that HTML, the email client on the receiving side won't display the images automatically. You may have to click "Show images" on the email.